# reload UITableViewCell only after Insert-Animation finished

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

so i'm inserting a `UITableViewCell` into my tableView.

```
[searchTableView beginUpdates];
[searchTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[searchTableView endUpdates];
```

after this i'm running an asynchronous request which updates the tableviewcell with a fade animation.

```
[someRequestWithCompletion:^(id data) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [searchTableView beginUpdates];
            [searchTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [searchTableView endUpdates];
        });
 }];
```

but it is possible that this request finishes before the insert animation is finished. if the request finishes after the insert-animation, there is no problem, if it finishes before and calls a `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` on the same cell that is currently inserting, the cell displays immediately and forces a reload while the insert-animation fades out.

is there a way to trigger the reload update after the cell is completely inserted? what would be the best way to do this?

if there are any questions, please let me know in the comments

Comment: Why do you need to reload an newly inserted row? Why not wait and insert the row once "someRequestWithCompletion" is done?

Comment: and here I was thinking, only tableview's can be reloaded :(

Comment: @KishorKundan You do only reload the table view. You can reload the whole table, certain rows, or certain sections. When you reload only one row, it's not uncommon for people to say they are reloading the cell.

Comment: i reload the cell after it was inserted because i update it with informations i get over http after the cell was inserted. sometimes it takes a while, so i need to display the cell immediately

Comment: One way is call the reloadRows method with a delay or reload the TableViewCell, after the tableCell is inserted, using the blocks and overriding the endUpdates method(set flag isEndUpdatesCalled) and setContentSize method(if isEndUpdatesCalled, ask the tableDelegate to run the reloadRows block) of TableViewCell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try This..

U can reload your TableView After Completion of Animation.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[searchTableView beginUpdates];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{
        [searchTableView reloadData];
    }];

[searchTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: indexPath, nil]
                       withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[searchTableView endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Three years later this answer saved my ass!  Thank you sir.